# IE7 clears session when I send download headers

Tags: php, internet-explorer-7, http-headers

So, IE7 keeps logging my clients out if they try to download files from my website. The files are downloaded indirectly with a download script which uses something like:

```
private static function SendHeaders($theFileNameServer=NULL, $theFileNameClient, $theMimeType, $theSize)
{
    $aBegin = 0;
    $aEnd = $theSize;

    // fix for IE catching or PHP bug issue
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Expires: 0'); // set expiration time
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    // browser must download file from server instead of cache

    // force download dialog
    header('Content-Type: application/force-download');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Type: application/download');

    // use the Content-Disposition header to supply a recommended filename and
    // force the browser to display the save dialog.
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$theFileNameClient.';');

    /*
    The Content-transfer-encoding header should be binary, since the file will be read
    directly from the disk and the raw bytes passed to the downloading computer.
    The Content-length header is useful to set for downloads. The browser will be able to
    show a progress meter as a file downloads. The content-lenght can be determines by
    filesize function returns the size of a file.
    */
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Length:'.($aEnd-$aBegin));

    self::FlushX();
}

private static function FlushX(){
    // check that buffer is actually set before flushing
    if (ob_get_length()){           
        @ob_flush();
        @flush();
        @ob_end_flush();
    }   
    @ob_start();
}
```

So, it seems the cache headers are somehow confusing IE7 and making it dump all cookies or something.

Any workaround for this problem? My login system works great in Firefox, Chrome etc.

Comment: Have you used something like Firebug to verify that the cookies are vanishing during/after the download, and see what's being sent out from the server during the download process?

Comment: Yes, I have confirmed that session is destroyed during the execution of the download script.

Comment: How do the users reach the script? With a get, post or multipart-request? I've had problems with headers after multipart-post-request in IE. Also try wrapping it in an iframe if possible.